# Store fetch data in a variable and use entire json as a prop in a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, fetch-api

i have the next code, the app should get a json from an api and  then pass the entire json as a prop so it can be treated in each component file and return the element to the screen.

The thing is i haven't found a way to just store the info from the fetch into a variable. if i just pass a json that is declared in the same file it would work just fine but can't make it work with the info from the fetch, the developer tools shows the json is being retrieved but it doesn't seem to accesed in the components, as you can see in the components part i tried to use globalData to use the json store in that variable but it breaks my app  and the console says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')"  in which name is is the first element inside my json.

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import Title from "./components/Title"
import Summary from "./components/Summary"
import Skills from './components/Skills';
import Experience from './components/Experience';
import Sideprojects from './components/Sideprojects';
import Education from './components/Education';
import Interests from './components/Interests';
import Courses from './components/Courses';
import Picture from './components/Picture';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";




 var cvdata = here i have a json with a lot of info, if i just write props = {cvdata} it would work just fine

  
function App() {
  

//  fetch('http://localhost:5000/api')
//  .then(res => console.log(res))

let dataGlobal;

const getData = async () => {
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api");
  const data = await response.json();
  dataGlobal = data;
  return data;
};

(async () => {
  await getData();
  console.log(dataGlobal);
})();

  return(

    
    <div className="App">
   
      <div className='Upleft'>
       <Title  props = {dataGlobal}/>
       <Summary props = {cvdata}/>
       <Experience props = {cvdata}/>
       <Education props = {cvdata}/>
      </div>


      <div className='Right'>
        <Picture  props = {cvdata}/>
        <Skills props = {cvdata}/>
        <Interests props = {cvdata}/>
        <Courses  props = {cvdata}/>
        <Sideprojects props = {cvdata}/>

      </div>





    </div>

  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Gotta throw it in `useEffect`

Comment: I will add that is better to store the data in a state. Like `useState` hook

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would help:

It can look kinda funky, but essentially the hook `useEffect` takes an array of states, which when change, fires the containing function. I pass an empty array as the second argument of `useEffect` to have the fetch for data only happen the first load of the component. The first argument is the function you want to fire, which MUST return undefined. async functions always return a promise, so to work around this, we instead nest an anonymous async function we call immediately so the `async / await` syntax is available to us.

hopefully the code example is clear enough. If you have any questions or I misunderstood your prompt, please let me know. Good luck!

```
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function App (props) {
  const [ page, setPage ] = useState("loading");
  useEffect(() => {(async () => {
    const res = await fetch(someWebsite)
                        .catch(err => setPage(err.message));
    if (!res) return;
    const txt = await res.text();
    setPage(txt);
  })();}, []);
  return (
    <div>
      This is the page: <br />
      { page }
    </div>
  );
}
```